# Bash tab completion adding space to variables

Tags: bash

I have a number of global variables defined in my .bashrc.

```
 export mylogdir=/var/mylogs
 export myappdir=/opt/myapps
```

I am able to cd $mylogdir. However, if I ls $mylogdir, a space is added on tab completion of $mylogdir:

```
ls $myl[TAB] -> ls $mylogdir<space>
```

Any option or procedure to stop adding the space. The space is a problem as I sometimes want to

```
cat $mylogdir/<space>logfile1.log
```

Tabbing through variables always has `<space>` appended to end.

Bash Version=4.2.46

Comment: Bash 5.1.16, works. if you do `ls $mylo<tab>` it also appends a slash at the end. Maybe a stray space in .bashrc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1412856/bash-ls-auto-completion-of-variables-adds-additional-white-space-at-the-end). In summation:

The space at the end is a preference that is set using compopt. You can see the current behaviour with:

```
compopt <program>
```

And you can change the behavior by running:

```
compopt +/-o <option> <program>
```

So to remove the whitespace from ls variable autocompletion, you would run:

```
compopt -o nospace ls
```

And if you want it to be permanent, you can add it to `~/.bashrc`